# Retrieving superclasses implied by OWL intersection classes

Tags: java, rdf, sparql, semantic-web, owl

An OWL ontology may have classes A, B, and C, and axiom (in DL notation):

> A ⊑ (B ⊓ C)

or in approximate Manchester OWL Syntax:

> A **subClassOf** (B **and** C)

It is logically true that A is a subclass of B, and that A is a subclass of C, but the triples

```
A rdfs:subClassOf B
A rdfs:subClassOf C
```

are not necessarily present in the RDF serialization of the OWL ontology.  For instance, consider this very simple ontology in Protégé and its RDF serialization in RDF/XML and Turtle:

[image]

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns="http://stackoverflow.com/q/19924861/1281433/sample.owl#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
  <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/19924861/1281433/sample.owl"/>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/19924861/1281433/sample.owl#C"/>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/19924861/1281433/sample.owl#B"/>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/19924861/1281433/sample.owl#A">
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
      <owl:Class>
        <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
          <owl:Class rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/19924861/1281433/sample.owl#B"/>
          <owl:Class rdf:about="http://stackoverflow.com/q/19924861/1281433/sample.owl#C"/>
        </owl:intersectionOf>
      </owl:Class>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
  </owl:Class>
</rdf:RDF>
```

```
@prefix :      <http://stackoverflow.com/q/19924861/1281433/sample.owl#> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

<http://stackoverflow.com/q/19924861/1281433/sample.owl>
        a       owl:Ontology .

:B      a       owl:Class .

:C      a       owl:Class .

:A      a                owl:Class ;
        rdfs:subClassOf  [ a                   owl:Class ;
                           owl:intersectionOf  ( :B :C )
                         ] .
```

The serialization has a triple with `rdfs:subClassOf`, but the object isn't `:B` or `:C`, so a query like

```
:A rdfs:subClassOf ?superclass
```

won't return the superclasses of `:A`. How can I write a SPARQL query that will return those superclasses of `:A`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you've got a class that is a subclass of some intersection class.  E.g., you might have

> **Student** ⊑ **Person** ⊓ **enrolledIn** some **Course**

In the Protégé OWL ontology editor, this would look like:

[image: Definition of student in Protege]

If you write a SPARQL query for subclasses, e.g.,

```
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

select ?subclass ?superclass where { 
  ?subclass rdfs:subClassOf ?superclass
}
```

and you don't have a reasoner inferring additional data, you won't see **Student** as a subclass in your results, but you might see an blank (anonymous) node:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
| subclass                                 | superclass |
=========================================================
| <http://www.examples.org/school#Student> | _:b0       |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

To understand why this is the case, you need to take a look at the RDF serialization of the ontology.  In this case, it's (in RDF/XML):

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns="http://www.examples.org/school#"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
  <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.examples.org/school"/>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.examples.org/school#Course"/>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.examples.org/school#Person"/>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.examples.org/school#Student">
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
      <owl:Class>
        <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
          <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.examples.org/school#Person"/>
          <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty>
              <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.examples.org/school#enrolledIn"/>
            </owl:onProperty>
            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.examples.org/school#Course"/>
          </owl:Restriction>
        </owl:intersectionOf>
      </owl:Class>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
  </owl:Class>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Or in the more human-readable Turtle (which is also more like the SPARQL query syntax):

```
@prefix :      <http://www.examples.org/school#> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

:Student  a              owl:Class ;
        rdfs:subClassOf  [ a                   owl:Class ;
                           owl:intersectionOf  ( :Person [ a                   owl:Restriction ;
                                                           owl:onProperty      :enrolledIn ;
                                                           owl:someValuesFrom  :Course
                                                         ] )
                         ] .

:Person  a      owl:Class .

:enrolledIn  a  owl:ObjectProperty .

:Course  a      owl:Class .

<http://www.examples.org/school>
        a       owl:Ontology .
```

There is, in fact, a `Student rdfs:subClassOf [ ... ]` triple in the data, but the `[ ... ]` is a blank node;  it's an anonymous `owl:Class` that is the intersection of some other classes.  A reasoner would be able to tell you that if *X* ⊑ (*Y* and *Z*) then *X* ⊑ *Y*  and *X* ⊑ *Z*, but a SPARQL query on its own won't do that.  You could make a more complex SPARQL query like this that would, though:

```
prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

select ?subclass ?superclass where {
  { ?subclass rdfs:subClassOf ?superclass }
  union
  { ?subclass rdfs:subClassOf [ owl:intersectionOf [ rdf:rest* [ rdf:first ?superclass ] ] ] }
}
```

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| subclass                                 | superclass                              |
======================================================================================
| <http://www.examples.org/school#Student> | _:b0                                    |
| <http://www.examples.org/school#Student> | <http://www.examples.org/school#Person> |
| <http://www.examples.org/school#Student> | _:b1                                    |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The two blank nodes are the anonymous intersection class, and the anonymous restriction class (enrolledIn some Course). If you only want IRI results, you can use a `filter`:

```
prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

select ?subclass ?superclass where {
  { ?subclass rdfs:subClassOf ?superclass }
  union
  { ?subclass rdfs:subClassOf [ owl:intersectionOf [ rdf:rest* [ rdf:first ?superclass ] ] ] }

  filter( isIRI( ?superclass ) )
}
```

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| subclass                                 | superclass                              |
======================================================================================
| <http://www.examples.org/school#Student> | <http://www.examples.org/school#Person> |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now, as final touch, if you want to make your query a bit smaller, since the only difference in those two `union`ed patterns is the path that connects `?subclass` and `?superclass`, you can actually write this with just one property path.  (Although, as noted in [Sparql query Subclass or EquivalentTo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21092246/1281433), you might run into some issues with Protégé if you do this.)  The idea is that you can rewrite this:

```
{ ?subclass rdfs:subClassOf ?superclass }
union
{ ?subclass rdfs:subClassOf [ owl:intersectionOf [ rdf:rest* [ rdf:first ?superclass ] ] ] }
```

as this, by using property paths, which also removes the need for the blank nodes:

```
?subclass ( rdfs:subClassOf |
            ( rdfs:subClassOf / owl:intersectionOf / rdf:rest* / rdf:first ) ) ?superclass
```

and you can simplify that a bit more to

```
?subclass rdfs:subClassOf/((owl:intersectionOf/rdf:rest*/rdf:first)+) ?superclass
```

and you can even remove one level of parentheses from that, to make it

```
?subclass rdfs:subClassOf/(owl:intersectionOf/rdf:rest*/rdf:first)+ ?superclass
```

but then you'd have to start remembering the precedence rules, and that's not much fun.  The query works though:

```
prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

select ?subclass ?superclass where {
  ?subclass rdfs:subClassOf/(owl:intersectionOf/rdf:rest*/rdf:first)+ ?superclass
  filter( isIRI( ?superclass ) )
}
```

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| subclass                                 | superclass                              |
======================================================================================
| <http://www.examples.org/school#Student> | <http://www.examples.org/school#Person> |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I am trying to run the query 
{ ?subclass rdfs:subClassOf ?superclass }
union
{ ?subclass rdfs:subClassOf [ owl:intersectionOf [ rdf:rest* [ rdf:first ?superclass ] ] ] }

 in the Protege SPARQL Query Executor but I am getting the error message MalformedQueryException due to the * .

Comment: Maybe Protege doesn't support all of SPARQL 1.1's property paths?  You might also try simplifying that portion to `?subclass rdfs:subClassOf/owl:intersectionOf/rdf:rest*/rdf:first ?superclass`.  There's no real need for all the blank nodes.

Comment: Of course, once you take that approach, you can simplify the whole thing to `?subclass rdfs:subClassOf/(owl:intersectionOf/rdf:rest*/rdf:first)? ?superclass` and get rid of the `union` entirely.